# CSRF - Axios is removing headers

Tags: spring, vue.js, axios, csrf, nuxt.js

I am using Axios module for Nuxt.js.

I do have problem with `CSRF` token. Whenever I log in into the app, I cannot send any `POST` request. The response is always `403`.

***Axios configuration:***

**Inside `nuxt.config.js`**

```
axios: {
    debug: true,
    credentials: true,
    baseURL: `${process.env.API_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.API_HOST}${process.env.API_PORT ? `:${process.env.API_PORT}` : ''}${process.env.API_PREFIX}`,
},
```

**Inside 'axios.js' plugin / interceptor**

```
const EXPIRED_TOKEN_MESSAGE = 'Expired JWT Token';

export default function ({
    $axios, redirect, store,
}) {
    $axios.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $axios.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');


    $axios.onRequest((config) => {
        const configLocal = config;

        if (config.method === 'post') {
            configLocal.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
            configLocal.headers['x-csrf-token'] = store.state.authentication.csrf;
        }
    });

    $axios.onError((error) => {
        const { response: { data: { message } } } = error;
        // const msg = status === 500 ? 'Internal Server Error' : message;
        if (message === EXPIRED_TOKEN_MESSAGE && store.state.authentication.csrf) {
            store.dispatch('authentication/logout');
            return redirect('/');
        }

        if (process.client) {
            // store.dispatch('alerts/addAlert', { type: 'error', message: msg });
        }

        return Promise.reject(error.response);
    });
}
```

**Request call:**

```
this.app.$axios.$post('resources/add', data).then(() => {
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Reproduction steps - under the hood of request:

[image]

After I printed request config inside `$axios.onRequest` as we can see from above everything is set, but in networking not at all

[image]

Going further backend server is not receiving any headers:

[image]

With console log:

```
`2019-07-04 18:45:18.380 DEBUG 712 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2019-07-04 18:45:18.380 DEBUG 712 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.`
```

Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: The picture shows the CORS preflight OPTIONS request with the headers in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. That request has to succeed before the browser will send the real POST request with the headers you're expecting. None of this is specific to axios, it's a browser thing.

Comment: @skirtle How could I solve that ?

Comment: Most likely the problem is on your server. I suggest you start by researching CORS so that you understand what's happening. You are likely to end up with security holes if you try to fix this without a good understanding of how all the parts fit together.

Comment: @skirtle Whenever I'll try the same settings of request in Postman - it is working

Comment: Maybt this can help you: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/63

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki As you can see in my question - I do have same stuff, also it is JWT authorization nor CSRF